# Need a script for Excel that removes rows according to list of words

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of words in column A of the 2nd sheet, and I need a script for excel that does the following:

1. Checks the first word of column A on 2nd sheet and then filters column B 1st sheet by cells that contain that word.
2. Deletes all the already filtered rows that don't contain that word also on column C.

And then it iterates with the next word from the column A 2nd sheet list until it went through all the words.

Example:

Column A 2nd sheet:
hav

Column B 1st sheet:
have

Column C 1st sheet:
must

In this case it would delete all the row because altough column B contains "hav", column C doesn't.

Comment: For help in Spanish: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your description is rather poor, but I gave it a shot. Try this code on "Sheet1". Replace "Sheet2" with the name of the second Sheet. This will look into each work on "Sheet2" and delete all rows on Sheet1 whose column B contains that word. Not sure what you mean by column C, but that condition should be easy to add.

Let me know.

```
    Sub Test()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRowS2 As Long
    Dim Word As String

    LastRowS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    LastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRowS2
        For j = 2 To LastRow
            Word = Split(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "A").Text, " ")(0)
            If InStr(Cells(j, "B").Text, Word) > 0 Then
                If InStr(Cells(j, "C").Text, Word) > 0 Then
                    'Do nothing
                Else
                    Cells(j, "B").EntireRow.Delete
                    j = j - 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor description! I need that it removes the filtered rows that also don't contain that word in the column C. I don't know anything about VB.
Thank you so much Toeme!

Comment: Ok, let me improve my description: I need it to delete the filtered rows (rows that contain that word on the column B) that don't contain that word in column C. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm trying it with only the header and one row on sheet A and it either takes too much time or freezes (I don't know which one). Is there something we could do to optimize it? Thank you!

Comment: Teoeme, it works! Is there any way to make it faster? It takes its time when applying for 15k+ rows. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, glad to hear it works. Can you take a couple screenshots of what the two sheets look like and paste them here. Maybe that enlightens me to find a faster way.

Comment: Here is the sample file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ee0b1ca530229600e2ae9ab85211c06c20190122152022/ed8ca4
Thank you!

Comment: I can't download the file in this computer so, unless you paste images, it will have to wait until the night

Comment: Don't worry, it's not urgent. I believe it's better for you to have the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Delete Column By Criteria

### Links

[Workbook Download](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=41524741014146281166)

### The Code

```
Sub DeleteColumnCriteria()

    ' Worksheet 1
    Const csheet1 As Variant = "Sheet1"   ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cFirstR1 As Long = 2            ' First Row
    Const cCol1 As Variant = "B"          ' Criteria Column 1
    Const cCol2 As Variant = "C"          ' Criteria COlumn 2
    ' Worksheet 2
    Const cSheet2 As Variant = "Sheet2"   ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cFirstR2 As Long = 2            ' First Row
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"           ' Criteria Column

    ' Worksheet 1
    Dim rngU As Range     ' Union Range
    Dim LastR1 As Long    ' Last Row Number
    Dim i As Long         ' Row Counter
    ' Worksheet 2
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet  ' Worksheet 2
    Dim LastR2 As Long    ' Last Row Number
    Dim j As Long         ' Row Counter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Calculate Last Row of Worksheet 2.
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet2)
    LastR2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(csheet1)

        ' Calculate Last Row of Worksheet 1.
        LastR1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cCol1).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Accumulate ranges into Union Range.
        For i = cFirstR2 To LastR2 ' Loop through rows in Worksheet 2.
            For j = cFirstR1 To LastR1  ' Loop through rows in Worksheet 1.
                ' When value in cCol in Worksheet 2 is equal to cCol1 and
                ' not in cCol2 in Worksheet 1.
                If ws2.Cells(i, cCol) <> "" Then
                    If ws2.Cells(i, cCol) = .Cells(j, cCol1) _
                            And ws2.Cells(i, cCol) <> .Cells(j, cCol2) Then
                        If Not rngU Is Nothing Then   ' All other times.
                            Set rngU = Union(rngU, .Cells(j, 1))
                          Else                        ' First time only.
                            Set rngU = .Cells(j, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End With

    ' Delete rows in one go.
    If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete ' Hidden = True
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help! I've updated the description in order to make it more clear. Let me know if your solution fits what I need. Sorry if I made you lose time. Thank you again!

Comment: @Luan: I've updated everything. You can now download the file and/or copy the code.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it works with your workbook but not when I upload the data I need. Maybe it's because of the spaces? I'm sending you my workbook: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ee03cae38570187344243c05535f677920190121234620/3dda09
Thanks  again!

Comment: @Luan: [Here is the modified file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=30112621572843930791).

Comment: when I play the script it deletes all the data from first sheet for some reason. Thanks!